# What should I do with preferences etc. after deleting an application?

Tags: macos

When I delete an application, preference files in `~/Library` and other places usually don't deleted as well. How should I handle these files, should/can I delete them without impacting the system?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the files from the old apps. Never had a problem. Note: if you reinstall the apps, they will not retain any data from the old install.

Answer (score 1):

I use [App Cleaner](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-cleaner-find-remove-applications/id1013897218?mt=12) from the Mac App Store now, and the user interface is great. I used another app with a similar name, [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), but I like the one from the App Store more. The Pro version of [App Cleaner](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-cleaner-find-remove-applications/id1013897218?mt=12) is $3.99, I believe, and is an in-app purchase.

There is no harm in leaving those extraneous preference files in place as they are usually quite small. Let's say you install Airmail, try it out, and then decide you don't want to use it. You can move the app to the trash and delete it. If you leave the preference files in place, you could download it again in the future and your preferences (should) still be in place.

It is my personal preference to use App Cleaner and remove all related files when I delete an app.